# Combobox is not populated with delayed (async) data despite databinding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, combobox

This got me puzzled today and I stil l don't see what I miss. I've got a Windows 8 Store form with multiple comboboxes, 2 I show below. I can populate them using databinding to a number of Lists. This works. Now these lists are stored in the W8 local folder Storage and the program loads them back async but then it only populates the first 2 comboboxes. It does only update all comboboxes when I would delay "DataContext=this" with a few seconds or so. I would expect that when the List's are coming in async, the RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedClass") is called and populates the comboboxes but this is never fired it seems. I can leave away SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedClass}"  in the XAML or the SelectedClass code without any change in behaviour.

This a part of the XAML:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="machinetype" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,120,14,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="250" Height="30" ItemsSource="{Binding prMachtype}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedClass}" DisplayMemberPath="Descript" Grid.Column="2"/>
<ComboBox x:Name="position" Margin="0,2328,510,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="74" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="30" ItemsSource="{Binding prPosition}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedClass}" DisplayMemberPath="Descript" Grid.Column="2"/>
```

Then:

```
{
    public class SchwDescr
    {
        public string Nr { get; set; }
        public string Descript{ get; set; }
        public string Kind { get; set; }
    }
}

public sealed partial class MainPage : Page, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

    public List<SchwDescr> prMachtype { get; set; }
    public List<SchwDescr> prPosition { get; set; }

    SchwDescr _SelectedClass;

    public SchwDescr SelectedClass
        {
            get
            {
                return _SelectedClass;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_SelectedClass != value)
                {
                    _SelectedClass = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedClass");
                }
            }
        }
```

en this is the start:

```
public MainPage()
{
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.LoadData(); // This returns all Lists async, like this.prMachtype etc
        DataContext = this;
```

What did I miss?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `IObservableCollection` instead of `List` for `prMachtype` and `prPosition`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Andrew, but I fail to understand why the List wouldn't work either. The content is set only once on the start of the program and data binding should work against anything that implements IEnumerable, also a List. I did solve my immediate problem by calling a async method GetMyData, letting Loaddata return a Task and using await this.Loaddata() before setting the DataContext. But I would appreciate if anyone can explain why databinding doesn't take care of displaying these delayed data.

Comment: Checking this out further I think you are right. A List does not implement INotifyCollectionChanged and this is obviously needed to handle the 'delayed' loading. I was also told that I needed to do a get/set and trigger their property changed just as I do for SchwDescr for prMachtype and prPosition. I think either one should do the trick, I'll check and thank you again for your reply.

Comment: Happy to help. Sorry I can't explain this much off the top of my head; I just know that in my WPF projects that use binding IObservableCollection is the only thing that does the trick. INotifyCollectionChanged is definitely at least part of the reason.